# Can't seem to intellisense an entity (entity data framework)

Tags: linq, lambda, ado.net-entity-data-model

My code is as follows:

```
var contactGroups = context.ContactGroups.Where(cg => cg.ContactID == contact.ID);

var MyContactGroups = from cg in context.ContactGroups
     where cg.Contact == contact.ID
     select new {
     Title = cg.Title,
      GroupName = cg.GroupName 
     };
```

The result of contactgroups and MyContactGroups doesn't allow me to access any of the records of ContactGroups..

i.e. When I use *MyContactGroups* I cannot access any of the columns such as *GroupName* or *Title*.  For example, I can't use *MyContactGroups.Title*

I have posted the video of my issue here:
http://screencast.com/t/i0ydKQSou

Any ideas what I am doing wrong please?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MyContactGroups` is going to be an `IEnumerable<ContactGroup>`. You'll need to get an individual item off of it to access the properties of a ContactGroup.

```
foreach(var contactGroup in MyContactGroups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(contactGroup.Title);
}
```